# Slick - optionally including / omitting a large column

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

Suppose I have a table with a number of small columns, and a large (say BLOB) column:

```
  case class Thing(id: Int, small1: String, small2: String, small3: String, large: String)

  class ThingMapping(tag: Tag) extends Table[Thing](tag, "things") {

    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.NotNull, O.AutoInc)
    def small1 = column[String]("small1")
    def small2 = column[String]("small2")
    def small3 = column[String]("small3")
    def large = column[String]("large")

    def * = (id, small1, small2, small3, large) <> (Thing.tupled, Thing.unapply)

  }
```

Under some circumstances, I'd like to query the table for all the columns except the `large` column. In others, I'd like to include it. I prefer to use case classes rather than tuples.

Is there good pattern in Slick for doing this?

Options I've considered:

1. Having two mappings -- a "skinny" and "fat" mapping.
2. Splitting out the large column into a separate table, then joining it in if required.

Comment: Why not define `large` as `Option[String]` on the `Thing` case class and optional in the table definition and then add another selection `def` like `def allNoLarge = (id, small1, small2, small3)` where you don't select the `large` field from the db.  Then you leave it up to the calling code to pick which selection `def` is used.

Comment: @cmbaxter -- at the moment, my calling code uses things like: `val things = TableQuery[ThingMapping]`. How would that fit in with having multiple selection defs in the mapping?

Comment: you can still use the `TableQuery` as the starting point, and then use the `.map` method on it to produce a new query that only selects certain columns.  I'll add an answer showing this.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need here is the `map` function on your `TableQuery` to allow you to select only a subset of fields.  So something like this:

```
case class Thing(id: Int, small1: String, small2: String, small3: String, large: String)
case class LiteThing(id: Int, small1: String, small2: String, small3: String)
class ThingMapping(tag: Tag) extends Table[Thing](tag, "things") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.NotNull, O.AutoInc)
  def small1 = column[String]("small1")
  def small2 = column[String]("small2")
  def small3 = column[String]("small3")
  def large = column[String]("large")
  def * = (id, small1, small2, small3, large) <> (Thing.tupled, Thing.unapply)
}
val things = TableQuery[ThingMapping]

val liteThingQuery = things.map(t => LiteThing(t.id, t.small1, t.small2, t.small3))
```

So I added another case class called `LiteThing` that represents the subset of fields, excluding the `large` column.  I then use `map` to create a new query that will not select that `large` field and it maps to a `LiteThing`.  I have no compiled this, but I'm pretty sure this is the direction you want to go in.  I got this from the [Hello Slick Activator Template](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-slick-2.1), in the section "Selecting Specific Columns" (after fully expanding the tutorial info).

You can play around with alternatives like

```
def small = (id, small1, small2, small3)
def * = (small, large)
```

or

```
def small = (id, small1, small2, small3)
def * = small ~ large <> (Thing.tupled, Thing.unapply)
```

And use

```
things.map(_.small)
```